# The width of StackPanel inside the button is very narrow.(WPF)

Tags: wpf, button, stackpanel

I want to make a button with an image similar to the following:

[image]

For which I have written the following in xaml:

```html
<Button
  Style="{DynamicResource BotonRedondo2}"
  Width ="AUTO"
  Cursor="Hand"
  Background="#3b5998"
  Grid.Column="0">
  <StackPanel  Width ="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal"  >
    <Image  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="/Test;component/Imagenes/face.png"/>
    <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="LOGIN WITH XXXXX" />
  <StackPanel>
</Button>
```

But the result is as follows:

[image]

The width of the StackPanel does not match the width of the button.

Any suggestions on how to solve the problem?

Comments or questions are welcome

***UPDATE***

Maybe I should indicate that the button is in a column of a grid as follows:

```html
<Grid
  Grid.Row="0">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Button 
    Style="{DynamicResource BotonRedondo2}"
    Width ="AUTO"
    Cursor="Hand"
    Background="#3b5998"
    Grid.Column="0">
    <StackPanel  Width ="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal"  >
      <Image  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="/Test;component/Imagenes/face.png"/>
      <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="LOGIN WITH XXXXX" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Button>
  <Button
    Style="{DynamicResource BotonRedondo2}"
      Grid.Column="1"
      Width ="Auto"
      Background="Orange"
      Content="LOGIN2"
      Margin="3"/>
</Grid>
```

If I remove "Auto", the button looks like this:

[image]

***UPDATE***
The style that applies to the button is as follows:

```html
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BotonRedondo2">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Border BorderThickness="0"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          CornerRadius="4">
          <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: No. It remains the same. Thanks for writting.

Comment: StackPanel with Horizontal orientation does not fill the whole width. it only fills the width necessary for the items inside it. Use another control, perhaps grid with two columns

Answer (score 0):

`StackPanel` in `Horizontal` orientation stacks items next to each other. It basically doesn't  care about the `HorizontalAlignment` of items inside it.

You can use a Grid instead:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <Image Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="/Test;component/Imagenes/face.png"/>
   <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="LOGIN WITH XXXXX" />
</Grid>
```

The above will give you the desired look.

Comment: There is no change, the problem is which button has the option Width ="Auto", 
If you remove this (Width ="Auto"), your code or mine works, the problem is that the button is very small and I want it to be as wide as the grid that contains it.

Comment: Then remove the width and use HorizontalAligment="Stretch" instead. How do you expect we should know that information without stating it in the question ? And you directly saying: "The width of the StackPanel does not match the width of the button."

Comment: there is no help to get if you provide half of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `Width="Auto"` from the `Button` and to set `Button`'s property `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`.
Also, consider using `DockPanel` or `Grid` instead of `StackPanel`:

```
<Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <DockPanel>
        <Image Source="/Test;component/Imagenes/face.png"/>
        <TextBlock
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Text="LOGIN WITH XXXXX" />
    </DockPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: The button becomes very small, I put "Auto" to be equal to the width of a row of a grid that contains it

Comment: `Width="Auto"` means that the element width will fit its content width.

Comment: You should remove `Width="Auto"`, `Grid.Column="0"` will do the job (if you use `DockPanel` inside of the `Button`).

Comment: @FabiánRomo can you try removing `Style="{DynamicResource BotonRedondo2}"` from the `Button`? Just guessing...

Comment: The button becomes huge, bigger than the others

Comment: Then you need to investigate what makes it small in the `Style` with the key `BotonRedondo2` and override that property.

Comment: You might need to set the `Grid` height or the `Image` Width/Height.

Comment: Try to make the simplest skeleton work, then apply additional styles.

Comment: The Style has the following: <Setter Property = "Width" Value = "75" />, I removed it but the problem still remains

Answer (score 0):

In the style of the button it should be written like this:

```html
CornerRadius="4">
<ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```